# How to split text file based on startswith

Tags: java, file

I want to split file as Header with detail in a list based on sequence.

want to split the text file using Header and detail I tried something like this but doesn't help.

I wanted to call previous iteration of iterator but I couldn't...

**File :**

> H>>>>>>
>
> L>>>>>>>
>
> L>>>>>>>
>
> L>>>>>>>
>
> H>>>>>>>
>
> L>>>>>>>
>
> L>>>>>>>
>
> H>>>>>>>
>
> L>>>>>>> ...

**I wanted :**

> List 1 with H , L , L ,L
>
> List 2 with H , L , L
>
> List 3 with H , L

**Code Tried :**

```
 List<String> poString = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(poString !=null && poString.size() > 0)
            {      
               ListIterator<String> iter = poString.listIterator();
               while(iter.hasNext())
               {
                String tempHead = iter.next();
                List<String> detailLst = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(tempHead.startsWith("H"))
                 {
                    while(iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        String detailt = iter.next();
                        if(!detailt.startsWith("H"))
                          detailLst.add(detailt);
                        else
                        {
                            iter.previousIndex();
                        }
                    }
                 }
               }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try clarifying your question so we could help you

Comment: just edited I want to split as Lists based on file I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
        List<StringBuilder> myList = new List<StringBuilder>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
        if (line[0] == 'H')
        {
            myList.add(sb);  
            sb = new StringBuilder();                               
        }   
        sb.append(line[0]);        
        line = br.readLine();
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: but here will get Headers in a list and details in a list , but I want no of lists as I have no of headers with its details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this..

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> headers=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> lines=new ArrayList();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>(); 
    File f= new File("inputfile.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    try {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
       String ss=scanner.nextLine();
       String key= String.valueOf(ss.charAt(0));
       if ( map.containsKey(key))
       {
           ArrayList<String> temp=(ArrayList) map.get(key);
           temp.add(ss);
           map.put(key, temp);
       }
       else
       {
           ArrayList<String> temp= new ArrayList();
           temp.add(ss);
           map.put(key, temp);
       }
      }
    }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          throw e;
      }
```

}

Comment: but here will get Headers in a list and details in a list , but I want no of lists as I have no of headers with its details.

Comment: Hi if you don't know how many headers are there you can use HashMap. For every new header character a new list is created and added into the hashmap. For existing once, the list is updated.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood, eventually how many `H..lines` in your file, how many `List<String>` would you want to have.

If you don't know the exact number, (in your example, it is 3) then you have a List of List  (`List<List<String>>`).

```
//read the file, omitted

List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<<List<String>>();
List<String> lines = null;
boolean createList = false;
while (line != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("H")){
      myList.add(lines);
      lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
//if the 1st line of your file not starting with 'H', NPE, you have to handle it
   lines.add(line);
   line=readnextlineSomeHow(); //read next line
}
```

the above codes may not work out of box, but it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've tried a little on my own and it works

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<> ();
    int numlines =0;
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("H"))
            { 
                   result.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                   result.get(numlines).add("H");

                   line = br.readLine();

                   while(line != null && !line.startsWith("H")){
                       if(line.startsWith("L")) result.get(numlines).add("L");
                       line = br.readLine();
                   }
                   ++numlines;
            }        
            else line = br.readLine();
        }

    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```